# Fragment mDrawer menu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an simply webview app with mDrawer menu, and it work's like a charm on 3.0+ android, but i want it to work with versions under 3. I have read about v4 support and i added it to the project.  Application was a Activity then i changed to FragmentActivity because off support library . Sorry for my English.

Here's the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     WebView browser;
     // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
     private ListView mDrawerList;

     // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
     private String mTitle = "";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.loadUrl("");
         browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                        R.string.drawer_close) {

                /** Called when drawer is closed */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

                        invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }

                /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Menu");

                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }


        };
        browser.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                    switch(keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if(webView.canGoBack())
                            {
                                webView.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus));

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                        // Getting an array of rivers
                        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

                        // Currently selected river
                        mTitle = menuItems[position];

                        // Creating a fragment object


                        // Passing selected item information to fragment
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putInt("position", position);
                        data.putString("url", getUrl(position));



                        // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                        fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                                if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) finish();
                            }
                        });

                        // Creating a fragment transaction
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                        // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction


                        // Committing the transaction
                        ft.commit();

                        // Closing the drawer
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                }
        });     


    }
```

The problem is in

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                                if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) finish();
                            }
                        });
```

The method addOnBackStackChangedListener(FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener) in the type FragmentManager is not applicable for the arguments (new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener(){})

Comment: Just a note, since you are using support.v4 now, make sure all your Fragments, FragmentManager, FragmentActivity are classes of support package only :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the wrong `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener`.

**What you have**

```
import android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
```

**What you should have**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
```

Comment: Fixed and working, i'll test now on 2.3 thank you :)

Comment: Not working again same when i try to change getactionbar to getSupportActionBar() .... i got error  The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}

Comment: @SandraMladenovic [I think you should take a look at Google's example on implementing the `DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Answer (score 1):

use **getSupportFragmentManager()** instead of getFragmentManager.

```
 fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                        public void onBackStackChanged() {
                            if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)    
                                 finish();                                                               
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Not working again same when i try to change getactionbar to getSupportActionBar() .... i got error The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}